# Proving that if $n^4$ is odd then $n$ is odd by contradiction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

My attempt:

Let's suppose there is an even number $n$ such that $n^4$ is odd.
Then, since $n$ is even, $n= 2k$ where $k$ is an integer. 
Then, $n^4 = 16k^4 = 2(8k^4)$ which is an even number. Therefore, there's no even $n$ such that $n^4$ is odd.

Is this proof correct ?

Comment: is the final paragraph a typo ?

Comment: You should replace the sentence "Let there exists a number n . . . " with "Assume $n$ is even." Then, since that assumption leads to a contradiction that $n^4$ is even, the assumption than $n$ is even is a false assumption. Thus $n$ is odd.

Comment: Would you give it another look , i have edited it @Roddy MacPhee

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the statement using the contrapositive, which is an equivalent statement,  of the original.

Contrapositive: If *n* is even, then *$n^4$* must be even.

We can now build a contradiction from this statement by assuming *n* is odd.

Let *n* be odd, then there exists an integer *k* such that $n=2k+1$.

$n^4=(2k+1)^4=16k^4+32k^3+24k^2+8k+1$

$=2(8k^4+16k^3+12k^2+4k)+1$ which is odd.

Therefore, you have a contradiction to your contrapositive statement. QED